# How to create a brush same as the real pen tip in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I have a graphic tablet and I need to create two brushes for calligraphy in Adobe illustrator. So I need to create the following brushes:

- A brush gives the same font of the a real pen such as Uni-ball rollerball Eye 0.7m.
- A brush gives the same font of copperplate nib (Brause EF66).

Example

[image]

Comment: Both those nibs essentially lay down a round tip. Any difference is how the ink hits the paper, not from the tip itself. I'm afraid you'll have to be a bit more descriptive in your question with possible samples of the lines you wish to create. Otherwise, you can simply use the built in blob brush set to a small radius.

Comment: well I need a brush that gives the same line of a pen

Comment: Every pen provides a different line. You will have to provide samples.

Comment: I did, please check the example.

Comment: Okay, that sample was not created with a Uniball roller or a Brause EF66 nib. That's created with something more along the lines of a Speedball C0 nib and the talented hand of a calligrapher. If you are seeking the varied line weights, have you looked at the Width Tool in Illustrator? Have you tried creating a flat brush and using it as a calligraphy pen? There is *nothing* automated which is going to be a substitution for the talent and skill of a calligrapher.

Comment: Ok, I will try those suggestions. The problem is i'm not sure which setting I should use to create a brush that close to the regular pen. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Any of Illustrator's default calligraphy brushes would be close. The brush is really only 10% of the work, the other 90% is your eye and hand.

Comment: ok I will You also mention to use that DrawScribe in somewhere else in that forum. Well to be honest the tool is amazing, but it's split to two plugins. So which one will help more to trace a calligraphy drawing, i think InkScribe will be the one

Comment: DrawScribe merged into DynamicSketch but I'm not convinced you need it for this. A Calligraphy brush in Illustrator and a skilled hand can create calligraphy without any plug ins.

Comment: I agree, I think I need it, if I do a paper work then scan it. Well I'm excellent in paper, when it comes to Adobe illustrator, I don't know how to trace my work using adobe pen professionally.